# Can a transitive join loop infinitely?

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

I have a table that stores alternative product:

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| alternate_id | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_id   | varchar(36) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product1     | bigint(20)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product2     | bigint(20)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to find products that are equal transitively, like so:

[image]

In the above I'd want to query all of the products that are alternates for A (which should be B, C, and D), so:

```
SELECT ... FROM table
-- some cool join
WHERE product1 = A
```

Is this even possible with SQL?

Comment: If your version of MySQL supports recursive common table expressions, yes. Otherwise you will have to add additional information to your model.  You can google for "Nested Sets", "Materialized Path", "Transitive Closure". You might also be interested in this classical paper: https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/libkin/papers/tc-sql.pdf

Comment: Could you just tell us what you want with a schema and data rather than confusing stuff with A B C D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like (MySQL 8+ version needed):

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
products AS ( SELECT product1 p1, product2 p2
              FROM test
            UNION
              SELECT product2 p1, product1 p2
              FROM test
            UNION
              SELECT p.p1, t.product2
              FROM products p, test t
              WHERE p.p2 = t.product1
            UNION
              SELECT p.p1, t.product1
              FROM products p, test t
              WHERE p.p2 = t.product2
           )
SELECT p1 product, GROUP_CONCAT(p2 ORDER BY p2) alternatives
FROM products 
GROUP BY p1
ORDER BY p1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46f6c44b45cf2929e7e0e9107effeacb)

On MySQL 5.x the task can be solved in the Stored Procedure form (emulate CTE using temporary table, loop until records count not altered).

Draft code (must be debugged):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAlternatives ()
BEGIN
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS products;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE products (p1 BIGINT, p2 BIGINT, UNIQUE (p1, p2)) Engine = MEMORY;
  INSERT INTO products (p1, p2)
      SELECT product1 p1, product2 p2
      FROM test
    UNION
      SELECT product2 p1, product1 p2
      FROM test;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt1 FROM products;
  LOOP
    INSERT IGNORE INTO products (p1, p2)
        SELECT p.p1, t.product2
        FROM products p, test t
        WHERE p.p2 = t.product1
      UNION
        SELECT p.p1, t.product1
        FROM products p, test t
        WHERE p.p2 = t.product2;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt2 FROM products;
    IF @cnt1 = @cnt2 THEN
      LEAVE LOOP;
    END IF;
    SET @cnt2 := @cnt1;
  END LOOP;
  SELECT p1 product, GROUP_CONCAT(p2 ORDER BY p2) alternatives
  FROM products 
  GROUP BY p1
  ORDER BY p1;
END
```

But I recommend you to alter your DB structure and create "product group" entity. So the table structure will be altered to `(company_id, product_id, product_group_id)`, where `product_group_id` is a reference to the `product_group` table.

Answer (score 0):

The above code shows how to deal with your request in both directions.
First, it declares the DDL in memory tables, then, shows the results in both directions, yes, it was not requested but I wanted to check myself it this was possible. Then, makes a UNION to select records from both directions, forward and backwards:

```
WITH CTE1 AS -- FORWARD DIRECTION
(
    SELECT product1, product2 FROM TestData WHERE [product1] = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.product1, A.product2
        FROM TestData A
        INNER JOIN CTE1
            ON CTE1.product2 = A.product1
),
CTE2 AS     -- BACWARDS DIRECTION
(
    SELECT product1, product2 FROM TestData WHERE [product1] = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A.product1, A.product2
        FROM TestData A
        INNER JOIN CTE2
            ON CTE2.product1 = A.product2
)
SELECT * FROM CTE1
UNION
SELECT * FROM CTE2 ;
```

Comment: Ops... I just realised that it is about MySQL and I pasted syntax for SQL-Server... not sure if that will work in MySQL and I don't know if it has the equivalent to the CTE's (Common Table Expresions).

Comment: This would be amazing if it works. Unfortunately we're on MySQL 5.7. Version 8.0 does have CTE's. I couldn't figure out a way of writing this in MySQL 5.7.

Comment: Unfortunately I have basic knowledge about MySQL so, I cannot help you but if CTE's are available in MySQL should be easy to translate.

Comment: I see that MySQL also allows CTE's with very similar Syntax and allowing recursivity [Recursivity with MySQL CTE's](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-recursive-cte/). Maybe the updated code works, you will need to adapt the table name